# azure pipelines set user defined variable without using bash

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I want to set a user defined variable in an Azure pipeline without using bash - I am on a windows machine
In my pipeline a declare a variable

```
variables:
- name: BuildDir
  value: "test"
```

Later in the script I try to set it in a script

`- script: set BuildDir=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
but doing so does not work
I have tried using
`- script: set $(BuildDir)=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
And this does not work either.
What is the correct syntax please

Comment: Thanks for input, I knew I could do that. My question was how to change the initial value in one of my pipeline jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of variable `BuildDir` like `value: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)`.

Taking the following YAML as an example, the values of `BuildDir` and `Agent.BuildDirectory` are the same.

```
variables:
- name: BuildDir
  value: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo The value of BuildDir: $(BuildDir)
      echo The value of Agent.BuildDirectory: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
```

The result from the log:

[image]

---

Update:

You can use [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) `##vso[task.setvariable]value` in a PowerShell task to modify the value of a variable. If you're setting a variable from one stage to another, use `isOutput=true` to set the variable as an output variable in the logging command and use `stageDependencies` in the stage consuming the variable. See the example below.

```
variables:
- name: BuildDir
  value: Test

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Change the value of BuildDir
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildDir;isOutput=true]$(Agent.BuildDirectory)"'
      name: setvar

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    BuildDir: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['setvar.BuildDir'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Print the new value of BuildDir in stageB
      inputs:
        script: 'echo The new value of BuildDir: $(BuildDir)'
```

See more info about output variable from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable).

You can see the new value of `BuildDir` in stageB as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for input, I knew I could do that. My question was how to change the initial value in one of my pipeline jobs.

Comment: @RoachFIsher, To change the initial value of one variable, you can use logging command. I have updated my answer above, you can see the details.

Comment: OK so I can do that in the first stage of my pipeline, however the new value is not carried forward to the next stage?

Comment: @RoachFIsher, about how to set the value of one variable in one stage and consume in another stage, I have updated in my answer.